# MainList is missing a QuerySet. Define MainList.model, MainList.queryset, or override MainList.get_queryset()

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

Hi there I am trying to have a homepage where I can list from a model called Lecturer and create forms from a model called DistributionForm. I tried it with the CreateView but I got the error **MainList is missing a QuerySet. Define MainList.model, MainList.queryset, or override MainList.get_queryset().**
in the that the queryset is missing. Can you please help me.

Views.py

```
class MainList(generic.CreateView):
    template_name='home.html'
    form=DistributionForm
    models=Lecturer
    fields=['distribution','semester','lecture','lecturer']
    success_url = "/home"


    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author=self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context ['lecturer_list'] = Lecturer.objects.order_by('lecturer')
        return context
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


app_name='distribution'

urlpatterns=[
    path('home/',views.MainList.as_view(),name='home'),
    path('hocalar/<slug:slug>/',views.LecturerDistribution.as_view(),name='lecturer_distribution'),
    path('dersler/<slug:slug>/',views.LectureDistribution.as_view(),name='lecture_distribution'),
]



urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and my home.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{%block content%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


<div class="container">
        <div class="form-group pull-right">
    <input type="text" class="search form-control" placeholder="Ara">
        </div>
        <span class="counter pull-right"></span>
        <table class="table table-hover results">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th >Hoca</th>
        <th >Ders</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="warning no-result">
        <td><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Sonuç Yok</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            {%for lec in lecturer_list%}
        <tr>
        <td>
                    <p ><a style="text-decoration:none" href="{% url 'distribution:lecturer_distribution' slug=lec.slug%}">{{lec.lecturer}}</a></p>
        </td>
        <td>
                    {%for ders in lec.lecture.all%}
                        <a style="text-decoration:none" href="{% url 'distribution:lecture_distribution' slug=ders.slug%}">{{ders.lecture}}</a>,
                    {% endfor%}
                </td>
        </tr>
            {%endfor%}
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>



<div class="col-md-2 float-right ">
  <button style= "position: fixed; top:175px; " type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Add New Distribution</button>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Distribution</h5>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <form method="post" style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
         {% csrf_token %}
         {{ form|crispy }}
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
             </form>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<style >
        body{
  padding:20px 20px;
}

.results tr[visible='false'],
.no-result{
  display:none;
}

.results tr[visible='true']{
  display:table-row;
}

.counter{
  padding:8px;
  color:#ccc;
}
    </style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".search").keyup(function () {
    var searchTerm = $(".search").val();
    var listItem = $('.results tbody').children('tr');
    var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('")

  $.extend($.expr[':'], {'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array){
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
  });

  $(".results tbody tr").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e){
    $(this).attr('visible','false');
  });

  $(".results tbody tr:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e){
    $(this).attr('visible','true');
  });

  var jobCount = $('.results tbody tr[visible="true"]').length;

  if(jobCount == '0') {$('.no-result').show();}
    else {$('.no-result').hide();}
          });
});
</script>



{% endblock content%}
```

**EDIT**

```
class MainList(generic.CreateView):
    template_name='home.html'
    model=Distribution
    fields=['distribution','semester','lecture','lecturer']
    success_url = "/home"


    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author=self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context ['lecturer_list'] = Lecturer.objects.order_by('lecturer')
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

I think adding a class attribute as `queryset = Lecturer.objects.all()` to `MainList` (or any queryset that you want based on `Lecturer` model) or defining a `get_queryset` method like following codes:

```
class MainList(generic.CreateView):
    template_name='home.html'
    form=DistributionForm
    models=Lecturer
    fields=['distribution','semester','lecture','lecturer']
    success_url = "/home"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Lecturer.objects.all()

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author=self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context ['lecturer_list'] = Lecturer.objects.order_by('lecturer')
        return context
```

will solve your problem. Another way is to change `models=Lecturer` to `model=Lecturer` in your class attributes (if you're not using it in other places) and only in that case you don't need to define a queryset for your class.

Comment: Now I posted my new view, the problem is now I get no error but the form is not saving